# how can i cast jsonb in postgres 12

Tags: postgresql

```
select
    id,
    cast((nd ->> 'bath') as float) as bath,
    cast((nd ->> 'bed') as integer) as bed,
    cast(ndp as NUMERIC) as price ,
    FIRST_VALUE(cast((nd ->> 'bed') as integer)) OVER(
ORDER BY
    cast((nd ->> 'bed') as integer)) priority_bed,
    FIRST_VALUE(cast((nd ->> 'bath') as float)) OVER(
ORDER BY
    cast((nd ->> 'bath') as float)) priority_bath 
FROM
    properties p cross 
join
    lateral jsonb_array_elements(p.bed_bath_price) as nd cross 
join
    lateral jsonb_array_elements(nd -> 'price') as ndp
```

I use postgres 13 and cast(ndp as numeric) works just fine,but on postgres 12 it gives cannot cast jsonb null .....

Comment: You can try `join lateral jsonb_array_elements(nd ->> 'price') as ndp` so that ndp is a text instead of a jsonb

Comment: @Edouard Not really, rather `cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(nd -> 'price') as ndp`.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm, yes you're right of course ... I was a little bit fast, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast JSONB null to numeric in v13 either.  The difference must lie in the data itself, not in the version of the database you are running.

You could write something like this `case when jsonb_typeof(ndp)<>'null' then ndp::numeric end`, or define a function to encapsulate this if you will be doing it a lot.